# Resize D3 SVG Element and Overflow on windows size change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am still in the process of learning D3v7 and create a heatmap, which I expand with more functions.

Now I have a problem to set the height and width of my SVG element when the Windows Size is changed.

Through several posts from the forum, I managed to get my SVG element to dynamically adjust its height and width.

```js
.attr(
  "viewBox",
  `0 0 ${i_width + margin.right} ${i_height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`
)
```

But now I would like that my SVG Element get an Scrollbar when the windows is to small that the font in the SVG element is no longer readable. I want a min width up to where the width is changeable and over it then an Scrollbar is created.

```js
const data = [
    { group: "A", variable: "v1", value: 98 }, { group: "A", variable: "v2", value: 95 },
    { group: "A", variable: "v3", value: 22 }, { group: "A", variable: "v4", value: 14 },
    { group: "A", variable: "v5", value: 59 }, { group: "A", variable: "v6", value: 52 },
    { group: "A", variable: "v7", value: 88 }, { group: "A", variable: "v8", value: 20 },
    { group: "A", variable: "v9", value: 99 }, { group: "A", variable: "v10", value: 66 },
    { group: "B", variable: "v1", value: 37 }, { group: "B", variable: "v2", value: 50 },
    { group: "B", variable: "v3", value: 81 }, { group: "B", variable: "v4", value: 79 },
    { group: "B", variable: "v5", value: 84 }, { group: "B", variable: "v6", value: 91 },
    { group: "B", variable: "v7", value: 82 }, { group: "B", variable: "v8", value: 89 },
    { group: "B", variable: "v9", value: 6 }, { group: "B", variable: "v10", value: 67 },
    { group: "C", variable: "v1", value: 96 }, { group: "C", variable: "v2", value: 13 },
    { group: "C", variable: "v3", value: 98 }, { group: "C", variable: "v4", value: 10 },
    { group: "C", variable: "v5", value: 86 }, { group: "C", variable: "v6", value: 23 },
    { group: "C", variable: "v7", value: 74 }, { group: "C", variable: "v8", value: 47 },
    { group: "C", variable: "v9", value: 73 }, { group: "C", variable: "v10", value: 40 },
    { group: "D", variable: "v1", value: 75 }, { group: "D", variable: "v2", value: 18 },
    { group: "D", variable: "v3", value: 92 }, { group: "D", variable: "v4", value: 43 },
    { group: "D", variable: "v5", value: 16 }, { group: "D", variable: "v6", value: 27 },
    { group: "D", variable: "v7", value: 76 }, { group: "D", variable: "v8", value: 24 },
    { group: "D", variable: "v9", value: 1 }, { group: "D", variable: "v10", value: 87 },
    { group: "E", variable: "v1", value: 44 }, { group: "E", variable: "v2", value: 29 },
    { group: "E", variable: "v3", value: 58 }, { group: "E", variable: "v4", value: 55 },
    { group: "E", variable: "v5", value: 65 }, { group: "E", variable: "v6", value: 56 },
    { group: "E", variable: "v7", value: 9 }, { group: "E", variable: "v8", value: 78 },
    { group: "E", variable: "v9", value: 49 }, { group: "E", variable: "v10", value: 36 },
    { group: "F", variable: "v1", value: 35 }, { group: "F", variable: "v2", value: 80 },
    { group: "F", variable: "v3", value: 8 }, { group: "F", variable: "v4", value: 46 },
    { group: "F", variable: "v5", value: 48 }, { group: "F", variable: "v6", value: 102 }
];

// Setze Dimension und Größe
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("heatmap")
var i_width = parentDiv.clientWidth;
var i_height = 450;

//const margin = {top: 40, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 50};
const margin = { top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 100 };
const width = i_width - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = i_height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const extent = d3.extent(data, d => d.value);
const max = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value })
// Holt mir die Unique Group und Variables von der Datenquelle für die X- und Y-Achse
// d[value] ist wenn value eine Variable ist 
// d['value'] ist das gleiche wie d.value um den Key aus dem Array zu erhalten
const myGroups = data.map(function (d) { return d.group })
const myVars = data.map(function (d) { return d.variable })

// Anfügen von svg Elementen zu #heatmap
const svg = d3.select("#heatmap")
    .append("svg") //Anfügen von svg an #heatmap
    .attr("id", "hm_svg")
    //.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    //.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${i_width + margin.right} ${i_height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`)

const g_area = d3.select("svg")
    // Anfügen einer Gruppe an das SVG Element
    .append("g") //Anfügen von g (Groups) an svg
    .attr("id", "hm_area")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


// Color Skalierung
const myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["#f9f9f9", "#6e69b3", /*"#69b3a2"*/])
    .domain([extent[0], (Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50)])


// X-Skalierung
const x_scale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(myGroups)
    .padding(0.01);
// X-Achse erstellen
const xAxis = g_area
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "hm_x_axis")
xAxis.append("g")
    .attr("id", "hm_x_axis_value")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .style("color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .style("font-family", "arial")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x_scale));
// Einfügen xAxis Label
xAxis.append("text")
    .attr("id", "hm_x_axis_label")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", height + 40)
    .style("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
    .style("font-size", "18px")
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Label X");


// Y-Skalierung
const y_scale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(myVars)
    .padding(0.03);
// Y-Achse erstellen
const yAxis = g_area
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "hm_y_axis")
yAxis.append("g")
    .attr("id", "hm_y_axis_value")
    .style("color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .style("font-family", "arial")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y_scale));
// Einfügen yAxis Label
yAxis.append("text")
    .attr("id", "hm_y_axis_label")
    .attr("y", - 35)         //Y ist hierbei die horizontale ausrichtung
    .attr("x", - height / 2) //X ist hierbei die vertikale ausrichtung
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .style("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
    .style("font-size", "18px")
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Label Y");

// ColorScale Legend
const GradColors = [myColor(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50), myColor(extent[0])];
const g_colorScale = g_area
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "colorLegend")

//console.log(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 100) * 100)
// Erstelle yColorscale
var yColorscale = d3.scaleLinear()
    // Mit Math.ceil zum nächsten 100er Runden
    .domain([0, Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50])
    .range([height - 70, 0]);

// Add scales to axis
var y_axis_color = d3.axisRight(yColorscale)
    .ticks(1);

//Append group and insert axis
g_colorScale.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${width + 35},${(height / 2) - 150})`)
    .call(y_axis_color);

//defs Element sind zum speichern von Opbjekten, die zu einem späteren zeitpunkt gebraucht werden
const g_def = g_colorScale.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "grad")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "0%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("y2", "100%");

g_def.selectAll("stop")
    .data(GradColors)
    .enter()
    .append("stop")
    .style("stop-color", function (d) { return d; })
    .attr("offset", function (d, i) {
        return 100 * (i / (GradColors.length - 1)) + "%";
    })

g_colorScale.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "hm_colorScale_legend")
    .attr("x", width + 20)
    .attr("y", (height / 2) - 150)
    .attr("rx", "4px")
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", height - 70)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill", "url(#grad)");


// Erstellen eines Tooltip
const tooltip = d3.select("#heatmap")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "2px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px");

const mouseover = function (event, d) {
    tooltip
        .style("opacity", 1)
    d3.select(this).select("#hm_node")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
};

const mousemove = function (event, d) {
    tooltip
        .text("Wert: " + d.value)
        .style("left", (event.x) + 20 + "px")
        .style("top", (event.y) - 10 + "px")
};

const mouseleave = function (d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
    d3.select(this).select("#hm_node")
        .style("stroke", "none")
};


// Erstellen von Rechtecken 
// Wird erstellt um den node sowie sein Label in eine gruppe (g) zu packen
const g_nodes = g_area
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "hm_nodes")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    //FÜr jeden Datensatz ein "g" Element erstellen
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "hm_node_grp")
    .attr("group", function (d) { return d.group })
    .attr("variable", function (d) { return d.variable })
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
    .on("click", function (d, i) { console.log(i) });

const rect_node = g_nodes
    .append("rect") //Anfügen von RECT-Elementen
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x_scale(d.group) })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y_scale(d.variable) })
    .attr("id", "hm_node")
    // "Bandwidth" ist über die Methode "BandScale" verfügbar
    .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", y_scale.bandwidth())
    .style("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d.value) })

// Einfügen der Labels zu den Rechtecken
const rect_label = g_nodes
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "hm_label")
    .attr("x", (d) => x_scale(d.group))
    .attr("y", (d) => y_scale(d.variable))
    .attr("dx", x_scale.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("dy", y_scale.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .text((d) => d.value);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>             
<!-- Code Vorschlage mit STRG+Leertaste aktivieren-->
    <head>              

        <meta charset="utf-8" />    <!-- Welche Sonderzeichen verwendet werden können -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    <!-- Wie sollte sich die Seite auf einem Handy verhalten -->
        <title> 1.Grundgerüst </title>      <!-- title als Tag -->
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>             
        <div id="heatmap"></div>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    
    </body>     <!-- HTML schließender Tag--> 
</html>     <!-- HTML schließender Tag-->
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
                const data = [
                    {group:"A",variable:"v1",value: 98},{group:"A",variable:"v2",value:95},
                    {group:"A",variable:"v3",value: 22},{group:"A",variable:"v4",value:14},
                    {group:"A",variable:"v5",value: 59},{group:"A",variable:"v6",value:52},
                    {group:"A",variable:"v7",value: 88},{group:"A",variable:"v8",value:20},
                    {group:"A",variable:"v9",value: 99},{group:"A",variable:"v10",value:66},
                    {group:"B",variable:"v1",value: 37},{group:"B",variable:"v2",value:50},
                    {group:"B",variable:"v3",value: 81},{group:"B",variable:"v4",value:79},
                    {group:"B",variable:"v5",value: 84},{group:"B",variable:"v6",value:91},
                    {group:"B",variable:"v7",value: 82},{group:"B",variable:"v8",value:89},
                    {group:"B",variable:"v9",value: 6},{group:"B",variable:"v10",value:67},
                    {group:"C",variable:"v1",value: 96},{group:"C",variable:"v2",value:13},
                    {group:"C",variable:"v3",value: 98},{group:"C",variable:"v4",value:10},
                    {group:"C",variable:"v5",value: 86},{group:"C",variable:"v6",value:23},
                    {group:"C",variable:"v7",value: 74},{group:"C",variable:"v8",value:47},
                    {group:"C",variable:"v9",value: 73},{group:"C",variable:"v10",value:40},
                    {group:"D",variable:"v1",value: 75},{group:"D",variable:"v2",value:18},
                    {group:"D",variable:"v3",value: 92},{group:"D",variable:"v4",value:43},
                    {group:"D",variable:"v5",value: 16},{group:"D",variable:"v6",value:27},
                    {group:"D",variable:"v7",value: 76},{group:"D",variable:"v8",value:24},
                    {group:"D",variable:"v9",value: 1},{group:"D",variable:"v10",value:87},
                    {group:"E",variable:"v1",value: 44},{group:"E",variable:"v2",value:29},
                    {group:"E",variable:"v3",value: 58},{group:"E",variable:"v4",value:55},
                    {group:"E",variable:"v5",value: 65},{group:"E",variable:"v6",value:56},
                    {group:"E",variable:"v7",value: 9},{group:"E",variable:"v8",value:78},
                    {group:"E",variable:"v9",value: 49},{group:"E",variable:"v10",value:36},
                    {group:"F",variable:"v1",value: 35},{group:"F",variable:"v2",value:80},
                    {group:"F",variable:"v3",value: 8},{group:"F",variable:"v4",value:46},
                    {group:"F",variable:"v5",value: 48},{group:"F",variable:"v6",value:102}
                ];

                // Setze Dimension und Größe
                var parentDiv = document.getElementById("heatmap")
                var i_width = parentDiv.clientWidth;
                var i_height = 450;

                //const margin = {top: 40, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 50};
                const margin = {top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 100};
                const width = i_width - margin.left - margin.right;
                const height = i_height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                const extent = d3.extent(data, d => d.value); 
                const max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.value})
                // Holt mir die Unique Group und Variables von der Datenquelle für die X- und Y-Achse
                // d[value] ist wenn value eine Variable ist 
                // d['value'] ist das gleiche wie d.value um den Key aus dem Array zu erhalten
                const myGroups = data.map(function(d){return d.group})
                const myVars = data.map(function(d){return d.variable})

                // Anfügen von svg Elementen zu #heatmap
                const svg = d3.select("#heatmap")
                                .append("svg") //Anfügen von svg an #heatmap
                                    .attr("id", "hm_svg")
                                    .style('min-width','700px')
                                    //.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                    //.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                    .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${i_width + margin.right} ${i_height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`)
                                    
                const g_area = d3.select("svg")                           
                                // Anfügen einer Gruppe an das SVG Element
                                .append("g") //Anfügen von g (Groups) an svg
                                    .attr("id", "hm_area")
                                    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


                // Color Skalierung
                const myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range(["#f9f9f9", "#6e69b3", /*"#69b3a2"*/])
                    .domain([extent[0],(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50)])


                // X-Skalierung
                const x_scale = d3.scaleBand()
                            .range([0, width])
                            .domain(myGroups)
                            .padding(0.01);
                // X-Achse erstellen
                const xAxis = g_area
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("id", "hm_x_axis")
                xAxis.append("g")
                    .attr("id", "hm_x_axis_value")
                    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
                    .style("color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
                    .style("font-size", "16px")
                    .style("font-family", "arial")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x_scale));     
                // Einfügen xAxis Label
                xAxis.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "hm_x_axis_label")
                    .attr("x", width / 2)
                    .attr("y", height + 40)
                    .style("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
                    .style("font-size", "18px")
                    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Label X");

              
                // Y-Skalierung
                const y_scale = d3.scaleBand()
                            .range([height, 0])
                            .domain(myVars)
                            .padding(0.03);
                // Y-Achse erstellen
                const yAxis = g_area
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("id", "hm_y_axis")
                yAxis.append("g")
                    .attr("id", "hm_y_axis_value")
                    .style("color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
                    .style("font-size", "16px")
                    .style("font-family", "arial")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y_scale));
                // Einfügen yAxis Label
                yAxis.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "hm_y_axis_label")
                    .attr("y", - 35)         //Y ist hierbei die horizontale ausrichtung
                    .attr("x", - height / 2) //X ist hierbei die vertikale ausrichtung
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .style("fill", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)")
                    .style("font-size", "18px")
                    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Label Y");
 
                // ColorScale Legend
                const GradColors = [myColor(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50), myColor(extent[0])];
                const g_colorScale = g_area
                                        .append("g")
                                            .attr("id", "colorLegend")

                //console.log(Math.ceil(extent[1] / 100) * 100)
                // Erstelle yColorscale
                var yColorscale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                // Mit Math.ceil zum nächsten 100er Runden
                                .domain([0, Math.ceil(extent[1] / 50) * 50])
                                .range([height - 70, 0]);
                          
                // Add scales to axis
                var y_axis_color = d3.axisRight(yColorscale)
                                        .ticks(1);
                                
                //Append group and insert axis
                g_colorScale.append("g")
                                .attr("transform", `translate(${width + 35},${(height / 2) - 150})`)
                                .call(y_axis_color);

                //defs Element sind zum speichern von Opbjekten, die zu einem späteren zeitpunkt gebraucht werden
                const g_def = g_colorScale.append("defs")
                                .append("linearGradient")
                                    .attr("id", "grad")
                                    .attr("x1", "0%")
                                    .attr("x2", "0%")
                                    .attr("y1", "0%")
                                    .attr("y2", "100%");            
    
                g_def.selectAll("stop")
                        .data(GradColors)
                        .enter()
                        .append("stop")
                            .style("stop-color", function(d){return d;})
                            .attr("offset", function(d,i){
                                return 100 * (i / (GradColors.length - 1)) + "%";
                            })

                g_colorScale.append("rect")
                                .attr("id", "hm_colorScale_legend")
                                .attr("x", width + 20)
                                .attr("y", (height / 2) - 150)
                                .attr("rx", "4px")
                                .attr("width", 15)
                                .attr("height", height - 70)
                                .attr("stroke", "black")
                                .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px")
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .style("fill", "url(#grad)");


                // Erstellen eines Tooltip
                const tooltip = d3.select("#heatmap")
                    .append("div")
                        .attr("id", "tooltip")
                        .style("position", "absolute")
                        .style("opacity", 0)
                        .style("background-color", "white")
                        .style("border", "solid")
                        .style("border-width", "2px")
                        .style("border-radius", "5px")
                        .style("padding", "5px");

                const mouseover = function(event,d) {
                    tooltip
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                    d3.select(this).select("#hm_node")
                        .style("stroke", "black") 
                        .style("stroke-width", "2px") 
                };

                const mousemove = function(event,d) {
                    tooltip
                        .text("Wert: " + d.value)
                        .style("left", (event.x) + 20 + "px")
                        .style("top", (event.y) - 10 + "px")
                };

                const mouseleave = function(d) {
                    tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
                    d3.select(this).select("#hm_node")
                        .style("stroke", "none")
                };

            
                // Erstellen von Rechtecken 
                // Wird erstellt um den node sowie sein Label in eine gruppe (g) zu packen
                const g_nodes = g_area
                                    .append("g")
                                    .attr("id", "hm_nodes")
                                    .selectAll("rect")
                                    .data(data)
                                    .enter()
                                    //FÜr jeden Datensatz ein "g" Element erstellen
                                    .append("g")
                                        .attr("class", "hm_node_grp")
                                        .attr("group", function(d) {return d.group})
                                        .attr("variable",function(d) {return d.variable})
                                        .attr("value", function(d) {return d.value})
                                        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                                        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                                        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
                                        .on("click", function(d, i){console.log(i)});
                
                const rect_node = g_nodes
                                    .append("rect") //Anfügen von RECT-Elementen
                                        .attr("x", function(d) {return x_scale(d.group)})
                                        .attr("y", function(d) {return y_scale(d.variable)})
                                        .attr("id", "hm_node")
                                        // "Bandwidth" ist über die Methode "BandScale" verfügbar
                                        .attr("width", x_scale.bandwidth())
                                        .attr("height", y_scale.bandwidth())
                                        .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.value)})

                // Einfügen der Labels zu den Rechtecken
                const rect_label = g_nodes
                                    .append("text")
                                        .attr("class", "hm_label")
                                        .attr("x", (d) => x_scale(d.group))
                                        .attr("y", (d) => y_scale(d.variable))
                                        .attr("dx", x_scale.bandwidth()/2)
                                        .attr("dy", y_scale.bandwidth()/2)
                                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                        .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                                        .style("font-size", "12px")
                                        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                                        .text((d) => d.value);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>             
<!-- Code Vorschlage mit STRG+Leertaste aktivieren-->
    <head>              

        <meta charset="utf-8" />    <!-- Welche Sonderzeichen verwendet werden können -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    <!-- Wie sollte sich die Seite auf einem Handy verhalten -->
        <title> 1.Grundgerüst </title>      <!-- title als Tag -->
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>             
        <div id="heatmap"></div>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>     <!-- HTML schließender Tag--> 
</html>     <!-- HTML schließender Tag-->
```

Does css "min-width" can help you here?

```
const svg = d3.select("#heatmap")
    .style('min-width','700px')
```

Comment: Wow, thank. This solution is so simple and exactly what i want. Dont know why i had not found this solution by my own.

Comment: Haha, It's often like that, that's why this site is made for. Glad I could help.